# Wrong memory offset with polymorphic structs

Tags: c, struct, polymorphism

I'm currently implementing a doubly-linked list in C. The purpose of the list is to be as generic as possible. Here's the node struct:

```
typedef struct list_node
{
    struct list_node *prev;
    struct list_node *next;
    int nodeId;
} Node;
```

Now, I'm extending this into the following node:

```
typedef struct history_node
{
    Node *node;
    String *cmd;
} HistoryNode;
```

Where the string struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct c_string
{
    char *array;
    size_t size;
} String;
```

Now, the problem that I'm having is this: I create a new history node, and set it's string to a value, "hello" for example. I then call on my pushBack function, that is defined as follows:

```
void pushBack(Node *node, List *list)
{
    node->next = list->tail;
    node->prev = list->tail->prev;
    list->tail->prev->next = node;
    list->tail->prev = node;
    list->size++;
}
```

The thing here is that when I assign `node->next`, instead of accessing the `node` part of the history node, I access the string, which results in disaster. I have no idea why this is happening. Looking at the addresses in memory, the pointer that is passed in has the correct address, but the address that is accessed in `node->next` corresponds to the address of `cmd` and not `node`. Any ideas?

Just in case, the code that calls this function is:

```
HistoryNode *node = createHistoryNode(buffer);
pushBack((Node*)node, historyList);
```

I have already verified that `createHistoryNode` works as expected, so that is not the source of the problem.

Comment: `Node *node;` you want to remove the star from here, and modify node creation accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want

```
typedef struct history_node {
    Node *node;
    String *cmd;
} HistoryNode;
```

you want

```
typedef struct history_node {
    Node node;
    String *cmd;
} HistoryNode;
```